# Disable pop-up blocking in undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to disable pop-up blocking using **chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")** and it has always worked, but recently I faced a problem that popups are still blocked and I decided to try the code below.

```
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Вut I get an error message

```
invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: prefs
```

I found a solution on stackoverflow ([How to pass Desired Capabilities to Undetected Chromedriver with Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551031/how-to-pass-desired-capabilities-to-undetected-chromedriver-with-selenium-python)) that I need to update the undetected_chromedriver (after the update I have version 3.5.4) to the current version. But I still get an error message

Maybe someone can tell me what the problem might be.

Comment: so are you trying to block the browser pop-up? Like Location, notification

Comment: @YaDavMaNish what do you mean ? I tried to use only the options described in the problem. I would be grateful if you could write in more detail